# onItemLongClick is undefined?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, onlongclicklistener, long-click

I'm trying to implement a long click in my listview item but it doesn't work and i get an error that says is `undefined`. Here's the code:

```
protected void setOnItemLongClickListener(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);// Error

        ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(position);
        try {
            Intent intent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

            if (null != intent) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
```

Someone has an idea how solve the problem?Thanks

Comment: `logcat` and `error line`?

Comment: @David_D see my edit. You have the wrong `return type` for the method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is most likely that you don't `implement` the listener. Something like

```
public class ActivityName extends Activity implements OnItemLongClickListener{
```

Try changing

```
protected void setOnItemLongClickListener
```

to

```
protected boolean setOnItemLongClickListener{
      // your code
      return true;
```

You need to use the proper return type for the method which is `boolean` then `return true` so the listener knows it was a success.

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html)

Comment: i've already written the implements but nothing.. Always `The method onItemLongClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ListActivity`

Comment: @David_D without seeing more of your code, I would suggest cleaning "Project --> Clean..." and see if that helps. Also, add the `@Override` annotation before the method. You may also copy the entire method, delete it, and paste back in. I've had trouble with Eclipse before where I needed to do that if I didn't do everything in the order it wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnItemLongClickListener
```

and add unimplemented method

```
@Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```

by default you can do this by right clicking on  OnItemLongClickListener select Quick fix

Comment: same problem.. the error is: `The method onItemLongClick(ListView, View, int, long) is undefined for the type ListActivity`

Comment: replace this 
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnItemLongClickListener

add its unimplemented methods

@Override
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
   long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

Comment: what i don't understand is; have i to put my entire code inside this method?

Comment: maybe i wrong something... can you take my code and show me what i have to do exactly? i get a lot errors :( also in the rest of activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39842/discussion-between-morroko-and-david-d)

Answer (score 0):

try this listener for Listview :

```
istView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), ((TextView)arg1).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: replace your listener with this listener.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
yourListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            //YOUR_CODE_HERE

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: to access items on listView AdapterView is taken. So use override method of that that listen for the long click event

Answer (score 0):

try to add this lines to your list adapter

```
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and the method is try to overwrite your method

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(
        AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Comment: mmh my list become not clickable adding the code in the list adapter :(